# maven plugin configuration to gradle

Tags: maven, gradle

I'm trying to convert this plugin in pom to gradle. And I've added 
`compile 'org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1'` in the dependencies.  There are some other parameters like "includeProjectDependencies" and so on. Just don't know what else to put in "JavaExec":

```
 task executeJava(type:JavaExec) {
   main = "com.abc.efg.func.DocumentGenerator"
   classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
   dependsOn = files('/lib/tool.jar')
   args = [
        "--api_list",
        "metaapi@v1",
        "campaign@v1",
        "--output_directory",
        "$project.buildDir"
   ]
}
```

Here's the plugin:

```
<plugin>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>1.2.1</version>
                                <executions>
                                        <execution>
                                                <goals>
                                                        <goal>java</goal>
                                                </goals>
                                        </execution>
                                </executions>
                                <configuration>
                                        <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                                        <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                                        <mainClass>com.abc.efg.func.DocumentGenerator</mainClass>
                                        <executableDependency>
                                                <groupId>com.google.template</groupId>
                                                <artifactId>tool</artifactId>
                                        </executableDependency>
                                        <arguments>
                                                <argument>--api_list</argument>
                                                <argument>metaapi@v1,campaign@v1</argument>
                                                <argument>--output_directory</argument>
                                                <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                                        </arguments>
                                </configuration>
                                <dependencies>
                                        <dependency>
                                                <groupId>com.google.template</groupId>
                                                <artifactId>tool</artifactId>
                                                <version>1.0</version>
                                                <type>jar</type>
                                        </dependency>
                                </dependencies>
                        </plugin>
```